# RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply, RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log

Tags: python, numpy, nlp, nan

While training for word vectors I'm facing the following runtime problems in between my epoch.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:12: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  if sys.path[0] == '':
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:12: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
  if sys.path[0] == '':
```

On checking I found that somehow all embedding matrix values are becoming NaN. How do I resolve this issue? Where am I getting the NaN from? It is a simple training model written in Python and NumPy but I'm still getting this error. The link to my colab notebook is [this](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1LcTs1vNpCQ1fJxPUVQICqDIVaIRpcdZe?usp=sharing)

Comment: Log of zero evaluates to nan.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is occurring because you have a class in your word vector model that has a frequency of 0.  And, as @CJR said, if you take the log of zero, you will get NaN.

I would recommend debugging this by first checking your class frequencies across your dataset, and seeing if anything looks out of the ordinary.

Comment: now I'm facing other errors : ```/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:7: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in subtract
  import sys
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:90: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in reduce
  return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:9: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in add```